# Glue job failing as it cannot access temporary bucket in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a Glue job which is failing with the following error:

```
An error occurred while trying to read the S3 bucket lifecycle configuration
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to XXXXXXXXXXX.s3.amazonaws.com:443 [XXXXXXXXXXXX.s3.amazonaws.com/52.217.a.b] failed: connect timed out.
```

It is not able to access the temporary folder that is needed for the job. I am not sure if it is due to VPC settings or something I am missing.

Comment: Do you have VPC S3 Endpoint set up?

Comment: Are you using a glue connection in this job? Did you validate that the configured temp bucket and keypath exists, and that your glue service role has access to it?